# SVN Issue with branches

Tags: eclipse, svn

Question is on how to backport code changes

```
  ---------------------------------->Trunk Workspace
                    | 
                    |
                    |
                    |
                 Branch-1
                    \
                     \
                      \
                      Branch-2
```

Sorry for the bad diagram here , but i thought this explains better than me describing the problem

I need to apply  the changes that i made to trunk workspace (after branch-1 was created) to branch-2 .

What is the best way to do this?
I use Eclipse and use Subversion for revision control

Answer (score 0):

You just need to perform a merge of `trunk` to `Branch-2` using the revision range starting where you created `Branch-1` and ending at HEAD.

Assuming your WC points to `Branch-2`: `svn merge -r STARTREV:HEAD URL_TO_TRUNK .`

This is covered in the Subversion manual under ["keeping a branch in sync"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.stayinsync)

Comment: Starting from at least 1.6, SVN **does not require** range for all sync-merges